# irf840 power mosfet

Tags: mosfet, ac

can irf840 power mosfet pass ac and also is it possible to logically control it?
I have the need to control an ac motor with a microcontroller (msp430).
so whenever there is a dc signal from the microcontroller, the power mosfet should be able to pass the ac to motor?
is it possible with irf840?

Comment: A single MOSFET can pass AC, but the problem is that a single MOSFET cannot *block* AC. This is because there's an intrinsic "body diode" between the source and the drain that will conduct in one direction, regardless of the voltage on the gate.

Answer (score 1):

Most mosfets, when used as a pair wired together, can do this. Try googling solid state relays. One trick is driving the gates (wired together) using an opto photo voltaic device. There are plenty of examples on the net.